# Usage of Bash commands in Nested Loops in Makefile

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

I want to use bash commands in nested loops in makefile, 
my current code is not working. Can some one guide me what can be the problem. I have written a simple code in test target. Here, I want to go to a directory DIR_S/case1 and copy rtt.csv file into another directory DIR_D/rtt/ directory.

```
test: 
    cn=1; while [[ $$cn -le 2 ]] ; do \
        echo $$cn ; \
        ((cd $(DIR_S)/case\ $$cn)) ;  \
        ((cp rtt.csv $(DIR_D)/rtt/)) ; \
        ((cn = cn + 1)) ; \
    done
```

There is no error when I run this but i see this message and the line is not executed

```
/bin/sh: ((: cd /Users/Umar/Desktop/dummy1/case 1: division by 0 (error token is "/Umar/Desktop/dummy1/case 1")
```

One thing I noticed was that if type

```
cd /Users/Umar/Desktop/dummy1/case 1
```

at command line it will not work because of space, I also updated the above line 
of

```
((cd $(DIR_S)/case\ $$cn)) ;  \
```

to

```
((cd $(DIR_S)/case\\ $$cn)) ;  \
```

but still this line is not executed. 
Can someone guide me how to use bash commands in nested loops in Makefile.
(I have mentioned nested loops as I intend to add another loop after this loop)

Answer (score 0):

The Issue seemed to be resolved when I use bash commands without (( and )).

Comment: The use of `((` is for _arithmetic_ whilst `(` is for _subshell_. The use of single `(' is nice if you want to change directory and return unconditionally to the right place at the end of subshell. Remember that arithmetic done in subshell is lost when subshell returns...